# Subtract the list DateTime item with each other in c#

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a list contain 100 DateTime variable, I want to subtract the list item with each other to see if they differ by 5minutes. Can this be achieved using LINQ. I want to subtract "i" with i+1,i+2.. and similarly i+1 with i+2,i+3..

```
 for (var i = 0; i < nodeDetails.Count;i++ )
            {
                DateTime nodeTime1 =     DateTimeOffset.Parse(gettime()).UtcDateTime;
                for (var j = i+1; j <= hadoopNodeDetails.Count; j++)
                {
                    DateTime nodeTime2 = DateTimeOffset.Parse(gettime()).UtcDateTime;
                    if (nodeTime2.Subtract(nodeTime1).TotalMinutes > 15)
                        return true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Could you add some examples of what you've tried etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a LINQ query that selects two dates from the same list and `Enumerable.Any` to check of the timespan between both is 5 or more minutes:

```
 var diff5OrMore = from d1 in dateList
                   from d2 in dateList.Skip(1)
                   let diffMin = (d1 - d2).TotalMinutes
                   where diffMin >= 5
                   select new { d1, d2, diffMin };
bool anyDiff5OrMore = diff5OrMore.Any();

// bonus: output
if (anyDiff5OrMore)
{
    foreach (var x in diff5OrMore)
        System.Console.WriteLine("Date1:{0} Date2:{1} Minutes:{2}", x.d1, x.d2, x.diffMin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more of information would have been helpful, but I guess this does what you want to do:

```
var result = <YourItems>
    .Join(<YourItems>, 
        left => left.<YourDateTimeProperty>, 
        right => right.<YourDateTimeProperty>.AddMinutes(5), 
        (left, right) => new { Id1 = left.Id, Id2 = right.Id });
```

This gives you the Ids of the items, that differ in 5 minutes according to a specific *DateTime* column.